# Service killed before starting loop

Tags: android

I am new in android development. My service killed before starting loop..
 I started service from another activity like MainActivity

```
    package com.example.ch_m_usman.sharedtasklist.Services;        
    import android.app.IntentService;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.util.Log;

    public class ReminderService extends IntentService {           
        public ReminderService() {
            super("Reminder Service");
        }

        @Override
        protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    Log.e("check","")    
   //Loop does not start.

           for (int i=0;i<5;i++){
                Log.e("Inside for","");
            }

      }
     }
//How to use loop in intent service
```

Comment: *Service killed before starting loop* how do you know this? how did you start the service? from where?

Comment: show how you start service

Comment: Intent intent = new Intent(this, ReminderService.class);
        startService(intent);   @VladMatvienko

Comment: Have you declared your service in the manifest?

Comment: Yes...Service is starting but not starting loop...

Answer (score 0):

Use below code:

```
public class TaskConfirm extends IntentService {


        private final IBinder mBinder = new LocalBinder();


        public TaskConfirm() {
            super("TaskConfirm");
            setIntentRedelivery(true);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate() {
            super.onCreate();
           //Initilise your objects here like below... 
            taskIdList=new ArrayList<String>();
        }

        @Override
        public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
        {

            return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

            // get intent data here like below if required......

            if (intent != null) {

               String  taskId=intent.getStringExtra("taskId");

               }
               // apply your loop here .......
                 for (int i=0;i<5;i++){
                    Log.e("Inside for","");}


        }




public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
       public TaskConfirm getService() {
            return TaskConfirm.this;
        }
    }


    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return mBinder;
    }


    }
```

Start service like below from your activity :

```
 Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context, TaskConfirm.class);
     // put some extra data if required
     serviceIntent.putExtra("taskId","1");
     startService(serviceIntent);
```

If you want to access this service in other activity then bind that activity to service:

```
 protected void onStart() {
            super.onStart();

            Intent intent = new Intent(this, TaskConfirm.class);
            bindService(intent, mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
        }



private ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {

        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className,
                                       IBinder service) {

            TaskConfirm.LocalBinder binder = (TaskConfirm.LocalBinder) service;
            mService = binder.getService();
            mBound = true;

          // do your task on service-connected...

        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName arg0) {
            mBound = false;
        }
    };
```